# In R can I filter across all columns where at least 1 value meets the threshold

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello this is my first post- (not sure if I was meant to post here or github). I'm quite new to all this.

I want to keep rows where at least one value is above my set cutoff (2 in this case). I've achieved this in my example (molecule d gets removed) but I imagine there's a better way especially if I many samples.
Is there a way to select all the but the first column and apply to the rest of the table?

I'm trying to clean up my data by removing things which were low across all my samples.
I think the same result could be achieved by removing rows where everything is below 2?

```
> marker = c('a','b','c','d','e')
> sample1 = c(100,55,43,1.5,89)
> sample2 = c(98,45,22,1,0.5)
> sample3 = c(89,45,65,0.5,67)
> data = data.frame( 'Molecule' = marker, 'sam1' = sample1, 'sam2'= sample2, 'sam3' = sample3)
> data
  Molecule  sam1 sam2 sam3
1        a 100.0 98.0 89.0
2        b  55.0 45.0 45.0
3        c  43.0 22.0 65.0
4        d   1.5  1.0  0.5
5        e  89.0  0.5 67.0

> limit = 2
> data %>% filter(.[2] >limit | .[3] > limit | .[4] > limit)
  Molecule sam1 sam2 sam3
1        a  100 98.0   89
2        b   55 45.0   45
3        c   43 22.0   65
4        e   89  0.5   67
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With `filter_at`, this can be done.  In the new version of `dplyr`, there is `across`, but it will look for `all` instead of `any` (`|`).  Specify the columns of interest, if the column name patterns are all that `starts_with` 'sam', loop over those, wrap the logical expression in `any_vars`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with('sam')),  any_vars(. > limit))
```

-output

```
#    Molecule sam1 sam2 sam3
#1        a  100 98.0   89
#2        b   55 45.0   45
#3        c   43 22.0   65
#4        e   89  0.5   67
```

---

Or create a logical vector with `rowSums` in `base R`

```
data[rowSums(data[startsWith(names(data), 'sam')] > limit) > 0,]
```

Comment: What if I have hundreds of columns which are randomly named. Is there a way to refer to the indexes? I tried : 

data %>% select(2:4) %>% filter_all(any_vars(. > limit)

but then I lose my row names

Comment: @Wet_laber If you have column index i.e. here it is `2:4`, you can use that in `vars` or `filter_at(2:4, any_vars(. > limit))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowwise` with `c_across` to replace `filter_at`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across(starts_with("sam")) > limit))
```

Output

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  Molecule  sam1  sam2  sam3
  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a          100  98      89
2 b           55  45      45
3 c           43  22      65
4 e           89   0.5    67
```